# Motion layout Material design Expanded Button bug

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, android-motionlayout

I have an app with an expanded button implemented.

The button shrinks and expands perfectly fine in constraint layout or any other layout except in **motion layout**.

In which the button does not get expanded after shrink and in the extended state when the state of the button change to shrink on the click of a button then the text gets disappears but the size remains the same.

Version of material design link "implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-beta01'"

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_call_helpline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_emergency"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/red"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:cornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        app:elevation="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_call_24"
        app:iconTint="@color/color_white"
        app:rippleColor="@color/color_white" />
```

I have verified the code and it does not have any such constraint that prevents shrinking and expanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAB seems to be having trouble with being measured twice. (motionLayout needs to do that)

A Simple work around is to wrap the fab in a container
Like linearLayout
put the LinearLayout in MotionLayout

```
 <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/fabwrap"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   >

   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="hello"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:backgroundTint="#F00"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_battery"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```